# Get pixel color after alpha blend

Tags: c++, colors, rgb, alpha, rgba

I have a RGBA color like

255, 0, 0, 100

How can I get the RGB if it was put onto a white background?
eg. this red would become lighter and be more like

255, 100, 100

And the same thing if it were put onto a black background.

Does this make enough sense?

Preferably c++

Comment: Check the wiki article. It's pretty useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description

Comment: Someone posted another answer before that worked like a charm...  not sure where it went....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example to my comment:

```
struct Color
{
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    int A;
};

Color Blend(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    Color result;
    double a1 = c1.A / 255.0;
    double a2 = c2.A / 255.0;

    result.R = (int) (a1 * c1.R + a2 * (1 - a1) * c2.R);
    result.G = (int) (a1 * c1.G + a2 * (1 - a1) * c2.G);
    result.B = (int) (a1 * c1.B + a2 * (1 - a1) * c2.B);
    result.A = (int) (255 * (a1 + a2 * (1 - a1)));
    return result;
}


void Example()
{
    Color c1;
    c1.R = 255;
    c1.G = 0;
    c1.B = 0;
    c1.A = 100;

    Color c2;
    c2.R = 255;
    c2.G = 255;
    c2.B = 255;

    Color blended = Blend(c1, c2);
    int x = 50;
    int y = 100;

    // Pretend function that draws a pixel at (x, y) with rgb values
    DrawPixel(x, y, blended.R, blended.G, blended.B);
}
```

Comment: The page Ben linked to is quite useful as well. You'll have to be careful of what type of blending you want and how you blend since some are not associative (Blend(a, b) != Blend(b, a)).

Comment: Why are you using chars aren't they ints?  Also, how should I use this exactly? Do I need to declare a Color mycol and set the .r .g etc...

Comment: The above example is for 32-bit colors. There are 8 bits per component, which a char (usually, depending on platform) satisfies. If you open up an image in paint and use the eyedropper tool to get the color of a pixel on screen, you'll see R, G and B run from 0 - 255. I will post some code to use the above blending.

Comment: Im making an iPhone app and the function im using takes parameters r, g, and b that are integers

Comment: So look at your documentation. Does it tell you that r, g, b should run from 0 to 255? Does it provide overloads? Or perhaps you're using 128-bit (unlikely) colors where each component has 32-bits. What magic function is this that takes integers?

Comment: void BitmapSetPixel(int bi, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int a);  They should be from 0-255      http://www.dragonfiresdk.net/help/DragonFireSDKHelp.html

Comment: See the post for the updated code. Realistically, this would use unsigned chars and you can simply cast those to ints fine. However, the above works fine as well.

Comment: You don't want to do this with CPU, especially on a mobile device.  Your battery life will be terrible.  Doesn't the iPhone have an accelerated graphics pipeline?  OpenGL ES should be available and would do this a lot more easily and use less power in the process.

Comment: Using some windows SDK called DragonFireSDK, all I can do is set pixels on a bitmap surface.  This shouldn't be too bad, its only when the user clicks that this is used

Comment: I've tried this code out and it appears to be very close but not exact: (http://i.imgur.com/P2dToEw.png). Notice that the orange shape is now a lot darker than it was before.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the blending function.

Nine different blending functions, with a formula for each, are described in the [`glBlendFunc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537046.aspx) documentation.

Comment: The term alpha blending means one particular blending function - in OpenGL, it would be (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). Anything else is "blending", but not "alpha blending".

Comment: @Stefan: There are still different functions, depending on whether you are using premultiplied alpha.

Comment: True, the formula in the premultiplied alpha case is different.